# Adding loading bar Ionic App - Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

How can i Add a `loading or please waiting` in between 2 routes .

for example when i go to page like details.html,this pas has **http** till page loads up user see a blank page .

i want something like this :

**factory**

```
 .factory('DrupalNode', function ($http, $stateParams, REMOTE_URL) {

        return {
            node: $http.get(REMOTE_URL + 'all/')

//////////////// please wait

        }
    });
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('detailController', function($scope, DrupalNode, $state, $window){

    DrupalNode.node.success(function(data){  

/////////disappear waiting text 


        $scope.innerData = data;
        $scope.whichArticle = $state.params.Nid;
        console.log(data);


    });
    $scope.goBack = function() {
        $window.history.back();
    };

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [$ionicLoading](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/) service of ionic. Call its `show()` function at start of controller and `hide()` when you get response from api.

```
  app.controller('detailController', function($scope, DrupalNode, $state, $window, $ionicLoading){
            $ionicLoading.show({
              template: 'Loading text goes here...'
            });
            DrupalNode.node.success(function(data){  
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        /////////disappear waiting text 


                $scope.innerData = data;
                $scope.whichArticle = $state.params.Nid;
                console.log(data);


            });
            $scope.goBack = function() {
                $window.history.back();
            };

        });
```

And if you want some text shown in loading then use `show()` like this

```
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading text goes here...'
    });
```

Comment: thanks , where should i put this $ionicLoading.show({
  template: 'Loading text goes here...'
}); ?

Comment: @sani I have edited code in my answer. Plese look at code, i am using it right at start of controller before  `DrupalNode.node.success(function(data){`

Comment: thanks a million , and can we add a gif or aniomation here ?

Comment: It already has by default gif. If you just use `$ionicLoading.show()` without `template` option , it will show a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an http interceptors so on every http request this loading will show you can see my example below

first you have to make a service :

```
    app.service('LoadingInterceptor', function($rootScope, localStorage, notifications) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            if (!(config && config.data && config.data.control && config.data.control.pageOffset !== 0)) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');
            }
            return config
        },

        response: function(response) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
             return response
        } 
    }
})
```

and then you have to push this service to the httpProvider

```
   app.config([
   '$httpProvider',


   function($httpProvider) {

       $httpProvider.interceptors.push('LoadingInterceptor');

   }
```

])

and then you need to make your template and call the $ioniLoading to show and to hide

```
  app.run(function( $rootScope, localStorage, $ionicLoading) {

            //on broadbanding a 'loading:show' $ionicLoading will appear
            $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function() {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: "Loading...<br/><ion-spinner icon='lines' class='spinner-assertive'></ion-spinner>",
                    noBackdrop: true
                })
            })

            //on broadbanding a 'loading:hide' $ionicLoading will hide
            $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function() {
                $ionicLoading.hide()
            })

        });
```